# Angular Dependency Injection/Super() call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, httpclient

I am trying to extend a class and replace a dependency with another class that extends the aforementioned dependency. However, I am getting this error when I pass the injected instance of http to the super call.

> Argument of the type 'HttpClient' is not assignable to the parameter
>   of the type 'HttpClient'. Types have separate declarations of a
>   private property 'handler''.

This is the provider that I want to use instead of AuthenticationService because it is injected with MobileAppConfig dependency instead of AppConfig.

```
@Injectable()
export class MobileAuthenticationService extends AuthenticationService {

    constructor(appConfig: MobileAppConfig, http: HttpClient, cookieService: CookieService, userSession: UserSession, someService: SomeService){
        super(appConfig, http, cookieService, userSession, someService);
    }
}
```

This is my MobileAppConfig class.

```
@Injectable()
export class MobileAppConfig extends AppConfig{

    constructor(private platform: Platform) {
        super();
        this.baseUrl = Servers.STAGE.url;
    }

    set baseURL(server: string) {
        switch (server) {
            case Servers.PROD.key:
                this.baseUrl = Servers.PROD.url;
                break;
            case Servers.STAGE.key:
                this.baseUrl = Servers.STAGE.url;
                break;
            case Servers.QA.key:
                this.baseUrl = Servers.QA.url;
                break;
            default:
                this.baseUrl = Servers.DEV.url;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to mention that AuthenticationService is a local dependency module and has angular/common 5.1.1, same as the project I am working on.

If there is another way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve, then I would welcome those suggestions too.

Just did a bare minimum testing to see if I could produce the error in another scenario and I was not able to. No errors here.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInjectedClass {
    httpClient: HttpClient;
    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class MobileAuthenticationService extends HttpInjectedClass {

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(http);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use `public http: HttpClient` (or `private`) for dependency injection

Comment: not necessarily. public or private only makes them a class level property.

Comment: Does this help? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372318/argument-of-type-http-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-http-in-ionic-n)

Comment: I saw that too and actually had that issue a while ago. lol It does not help though as that questions deals with the deprecated @angular/http.

Comment: Please add the superclass Constructor. Also I'd like to see the imports in both modules. I agree that this is probably a dependency issue

Comment: @AluanHaddad If you look at the last part, the bare minimum code, that is exactly how the super class constructor looks like. Just previously declared private properties and assigned within the constructor. They both import HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: @AnjilDhamala I think I see what it is. Are you using a linked to develop the local package? Are all of your angular dependencies peers?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The AuthenticationService comes from a local shared module that holds a lot of providers (Injectables) that is shared between a mobile app and website. The module is installed as a dependency via npm and I've linked it to the mobile moudle I'm working on (via npm link). Both the mobile app and the shared local module have their own package.json with same @angular components (common, compiler, core...) versions.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala that's what I thought you meant indeed. Do all the packages lisr Angular under peeeDependencies  and with the same version

Comment: No, the shared module doesn't list angular under peerDependencies. Neither does the mobile.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala well they should. Also try `--preserveSymlinks`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168683/discussion-between-anjil-dhamala-and-aluan-haddad).